# How can I add a confirmation to a delete action made through Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have a function in JQuery that combined with PHP and SQL deletes rows from a table, deleting them from the database.

When I click on the delete button, the rows are instantly deleted, however, I'd like to add another level of confirmation that asks if you really want to delete it.

Section that deletes the rows by referring the function

```
$userObj  = mysqli_query($conn , 'SELECT * FROM `shifts`');

if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $dataArr = $_POST['data'] ;

    foreach($dataArr as $id){
        mysqli_query($conn , "DELETE FROM shifts where id='$id'");
    }
    echo 'record deleted successfully';
}
```

JQuery function

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkAll').click(function(){
            if(this.checked){
                $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                    this.checked = true;
                });
            }else{
                $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                    this.checked = false;
                });
            }
        });


        $('#delete').click(function(){
            var dataArr  = new Array();
            if($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                    dataArr.push($(this).attr('id'));
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });
                sendResponse(dataArr)
            }else{
                alert('No record selected ');
            }

        });


        function sendResponse(dataArr){
            $.ajax({
                type    : 'post',
                url     : 'includes/dbh.inc.php',
                data    : {'data' : dataArr},
                success : function(response){
                    alert(response);
                },
                error   : function(errResponse){
                    alert(errResponse);
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would help if you included the relevant HTML code as well (`#delete` button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has the confirm function that will return a boolean based on the user's selection of yes or no. You can use this to make the user confirm they want to delete the records inside of your click function.

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
         if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
            var dataArr  = new Array();
            if($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){
                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                    dataArr.push($(this).attr('id'));
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });
                sendResponse(dataArr)
            }else{
                alert('No record selected ');
            }
         } 
});
```